# Runtime error on Partial refresh

Tags: xpages

I need to do a partial refresh of multiple components as found here:

http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_events_and_partial_or_full_refresh

So I figured I would start small with just one component and placed the code:

```
XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{txtProductType}");
```

In the on client side click event of a radio button group.  When the page is displayed, I get:

```
The runtime has encountered an unexpected error.
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you should always check source for what exactly evaluations are evaluated to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The XSP.partialRefreshPost method requires a client side id and an optional argument. So in your case the correct syntax is:

```
XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:txtProductType}", {});
```

Comment: This method changed in 8.5.3; the second argument was not previously required.